# Как я могу отловить ошибку при неверной выдачи сертификата ssl?

Tags: android, безопасность, исключения, ssl

Нужно отловить ошибку когда у меня не верный ssl сертификат. Пытался найти метод который мне об этом говорит, но его нет. Также, сервер не возвращает ошибку если сертификат не правильный. Может кто знает в какую сторону смотреть или делал подобное?

Comment: направление https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html

Comment: О каком сертификате речь? Клиентском или серверном?

Comment: Речь идет о клиентском

Comment: Покажите код установки соединения. При неверном сертификате обычно вываливается `SSLHandshakeException`.